# Apache HTAccess Remove Query String for redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

It sounds like a relatively simple one but here goes.. I have a wordpress website called example.com It has recently been redeveloped using wordpress however the old sites structure used the following www.example.com/?page_id=22 I want to redirect anything after the domain name that contains /?page_id=[any digit] to the homepage, im having great difficulty in accomplishing this and I also think I may have issues because wordpress itself uses the query string page_id before the permalinks redirects kick in, I could be wrong though but any help on removing the query string directly after a domain name would be great especially keeping in mind that it is a wordpress install.

I have tried various iterations that look like the following to no avail

```
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^page_id=(.*)$ 
        RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/  [R=301,L]

        RedirectMatch 301 ^/page_id=(.*)$ /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule **right at top**, just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

`/?` will strip off any query string.

Comment: How we can pass specific page id?

Comment: @anubhava : this one not working please give better idea

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=([199])+$ [NC]

@anubhava This one working but this right?

Comment: It should be: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=199$ [NC]`, feel free to ask a new question if it doesn't work